# Converting Dataframe to .txt file creates an empty row at the end

Tags: python

guys.

I've got this problem in my streamlit coding (python lib). I've wanted to create a button where I can download a txt file resulting from a dataframe conversion. Everything was right, except for the fact that an extra empty line shows up in the end of the .txt file. It's like the cursor doesn't stop right after the last string and an enter (\n) is hit. Could you help me out here?

This is the snippet i have:

```
def convert_df(dataframe):
    return dataframe.to_csv(sep='\t', index=False, header=False).encode('utf-8')

txt = convert_df(df12_navision)

colunas_2[2].download_button(
    label="Ficheiro Navision",
    data=txt,
    file_name=f'Budget_Monthly_{current_year}.txt',
    mime='text/csv'
)
```

I've tried to search for a lot of thing in stack overflow and other websites, but I just can't adapt those solutions to my situation here.

Comment: "It's like the cursor doesn't stop right after the last string and an enter (\n) is hit": you mean there is a sole newline at the end of the text file? Could you show some actual example input, and example output of what you mean?

Comment: Note that there will be a newline appended after the last string. It's not bad (perhaps even good) practice to end a text file with a newline. The question is, is there a sole newline; that's not clear from your question.

Comment: First, thanks for answering, @9769953 . 

You can use this simples data example:

'''
data = {'Column1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'Column2': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']}
df0 = pd.DataFrame(data)

...
txt = convert_df(df0)
...

'''
I don't know what you mean by sole newline, but I think it is. Although I know it is good practic, I need to remove this newline because the software where I'm gonna input this file doesn't except empty lines.

Comment: There's no extra row or empty line. The last line is terminated by a newline, just like all other lines. If you open the file with a text editor and move to the end, the cursor will appear after that newline.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thanks for answering. If you open the text file with this data above as input, you'll see that the cursor is at the beginning of the sixth line. I want the cursor to stop by the end of the fifth line.

Comment: That doesn't mean there's a 6th line. It means the text editor put the cursor after the last character which is a newline. Did you try to import that file or did you assume there's a problem?

Answer (score 0):

There's no extra line. All lines end with a newline character. When the file is opened in a text editor and the cursor is moved to the end, it's moved after the last character, which is the last newline

This is easy to prove with the example in the comments. Given this dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Column1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'Column2': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Exporting to a BytesIO object produces 5 lines, not 6 :

```
from io import BytesIO
b=BytesIO()
df.to_csv(b)
b.seek(0)
b.readlines()
```

That produces:

```
[b',Column1,Column2\r\n',
 b'0,1,A\r\n',
 b'1,2,B\r\n',
 b'2,3,C\r\n',
 b'3,4,D\r\n',
 b'4,5,E\r\n']
```

**Saving with an unterminated last line**

It seems that the real problem is that some other software expects the last line to *not* terminate with a newline like the others. That actually breaks the [CSV standard](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt) which requires every line to be terminated. `to_csv` doesn't produce an unterminated last line.

One option to handle this is to write the output to a StringIO object and trim the final string:

```
csv_stream=StringIO()
df.to_csv(csv_stream)
unterminated_csv=csv_stream.getvalue().rstrip()
with open('Output.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(unterminated_csv)
```

Comment: Is there a way not to end with this \n? Sorry if i'm being stupid, but i am still seeing that the created txt file has the cursor in the beginning of sixth line. So it is, that if i hit backspace, i come back to the end of the fifth line. And then, i just can't go to the sixth line using down arrow. That's what i really need: not to use this \n that forces the cursor to go to the next line. (although i know it's good practice, because if you want to add another data, this new info is going to be append since sixth line)

Comment: There is no sixth line. I repeat, did you encounter an actual problem or do you just assume that the other software requires an unterminated line?

Comment: It just give me an error, and then, when i use backspace to put the cursor back at the end of the last populated line, it works fine. But if you're not seeing that the cursor is at the beginning of the next line, i don't know what's happening and i apologize to you.

Comment: I see it and I explain that this doesn't mean there's an extra line. I actually posted the exact bytes produced by `to_csv` in the answer. The error means your software requires an unterminated last line. If you use StringIO or BytesIO you can extract the contents with `buffer = b.getvalue()` and keep the data except the last character with `trimmed = b[:-1]`

Comment: @Lima_Couto I added code that trims the generated text before saving it to disk

Comment: I tried this:

'from io import BytesIO

def convert_df(dataframe):
    buffer = BytesIO()
    dataframe.to_csv(buffer, sep='\t', index=False, header=False)
    buffer.seek(0)
    data = buffer.getvalue()
    if data.endswith(b'\n'):
        data = data[:-1]
    return data'

But got the same output.

Comment: `to_csv` uses the OS's newlines. On Windows lines end with `\r\n`, so you need to use `data[:-2]`. The RFC standard specified `\r\n` as the line terminator although most applications work fine with `\n`. I used `StringIO` and `rstrip` in the answer to avoid creating multiple buffer copies

Comment: Thanks a lot, @PanagiotisKanavos. Without your help, it wouldn't be possible. I tried to vote for your answer but I'm new here, and I just can't. I posted the exactly solution that worked out for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @PanagiotisKanavos, I've managed to solve my problem. I'll just post it here so that you all can see. Further questions may be solved if you look up for it in the comments we shared here.

```
from io import BytesIO

def convert_df(dataframe):
    buffer = BytesIO()
    dataframe.to_csv(buffer, sep='\t', index=False, header=False)
    buffer.seek(0)
    data = buffer.getvalue()
    if data.endswith(b'\n'):
        data = data[:-2]
    return data

txt = convert_df(df12_navision)

colunas_2[2].download_button(
    label="Ficheiro Navision",
    data=txt,
    file_name=f'Budget_Monthly_{current_year}.txt',
    mime='text/csv',
)
```